# How can I record the network traffic used by Tibco RV?

Tags: tibco, tibco-rv

we using Tibco RVRD for both Unix and windows as the messaging system. Just wonder, other than buy HAWK from Tibco, is there anyway to measure the network usage, before and after RVRD compression?

Answer (score 1):

There is a really great tool for this called [Rai Insight](http://www.raitechnology.com/prod-rai-insight.php)

Basically what it can do is to sit on a box and silently listen all the multicast data and represent statistics even in real time. We used it to monitor traffic flow spikes with just few seconds delay.

It can give you traffic statistics braked down by multicast group, service number or even sending machine. Traffic flow peak/average, retransmission rate peak/average. All you can think of.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't really used it for such, but the rvrd web gui (default http://server:7580) provides some statistics on inbound/outbound messages and bytes.